# Protocol Buffers: reading all serialized messages from file

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I am trying to serialize and deserialize protobuf messages. Following the example from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial), I write:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(...);
ArrayList<AddressBookProtos.Person> messages = ...;
for (int i = 0; i < messages.size; i++){
  messages.writeTo(out);
  out.flush();
}
out.close();
```

When reading the messages back in, I would expect to write:

```
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(...);
ArrayList<AddressBookProtos.Person> messages = new ArrayList<...>();
while (in.available() > 0) {
   messages.add(AddressBookProtos.Person.parseFrom(in));
}
```

However, I always get only one result back in. Where are the other results gone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [`writeDelimitedTo`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/MessageLite#writeDelimitedTo-java.io.OutputStream-)/`parseDelimitedFrom` or implement your own delimiter-based solution.

According to javadoc:

> ... writes the size of the message as a varint before writing the data. This allows more data to be written to the stream after the message without the need to delimit the message data yourself. Use `MessageLite.Builder.mergeDelimitedFrom(InputStream)` (or the static method `YourMessageType.parseDelimitedFrom(InputStream)`) to parse messages written by this method.